# Adding a given String to itself a number of given times

Tags: java

In an arbitrary class, I decided to make a method for making a divider based on the character you want the divider made out of, and the amount you want.

```
public String divider(String s, int amount){
        StringBuilder repeated = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){repeated.append(s);}
        return repeated.toString();
    }
```

The method is defined in the `Catalog` class. 
And I'm calling it as

```
this.divider("-", 10);
```

in the `toString()` of the class. And I'm calling it in the main method as 
`mainCat.divider("-", 10)` 
mainCat is a Catalog object.

I've tried a bunch of different ways of multiplying a string by itself in a loop to make copies of itself but they all come up blank for me. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [Works for me.](https://ideone.com/DIVO2v) Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What exactly is wrong with what you have?

Comment: The method is actually returning the String result, are you capturing it?

Answer (score -2):

You better just use `StringUtils.repeat(str, count)`.